gpg: skipped "17FE7178DD4F****": No secret key on WIN 11
I have recently generated and setup a gpg key for which,
git config user.signingkey
17FE7178DD4F****
git config user.name
Subodh Pathak
git config user.email
subodhpathak????@gmail.com

also I have setup the gpg location to C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe
by this command
git config --global gpg.program "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe"
but on a commit message, I am getting error-
git commit -m "new version"
gpg: skipped "17FE7178DD4F****": No secret key
gpg: signing failed: No secret key
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object

also on gpg --list-secret-keys --keyid-format LONG
I am getting -
sec   rsa4096/17FE7178DD4F**** 2024-09-13 [SC] [expires: 2026-09-13]
18B968642A3C3695E3AC4A5117FE7178DD4F****
uid            [ultimate] Subodh Pathak subodhpathak????@gmail.com
ssb   rsa4096/0EE875A14DDF#### 2024-09-13 [E] [expires: 2025-09-13]
I ran all the processes from this documentation -
https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/generating-a-new-gpg-key
I tried running
git commit -m "new version"
and I was expecting it to commit the changes made

Hi Subodh, if you solved the issue, you can answer the question yourself and mark it answered.

I got an answer exploring and googling, do not use git bash as a CLI {don't know why, it comes with its own shell Mingw64).
I used Powershell with adminstrators permission. Also I didn't used other cli's
So, if you are curious what happen using other terminl please hit a try.
